# Querying through a Rails Association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have two models: Shops and Users.  Users `belong_to` Shops and a Shop `has_many` Users.  Users and Shops are created separately, and then a User adds a Shop which changes its `shop_id` to `@shop.id`.

I need `@shop.users` to query all the users that `belong_to` shop.  I'm not sure how to make this happen though.  Currently, the only connection is the association and `@user.shop_id` is updated to the correct shop when the User picks a shop with this button:

View:

```
<%= link_to 'Add As Your Shop', update_shop_url(id: @user.id, shop_id: @shop.id), class: 'button blue-button', data: { method: 'post' } %>
```

Controller:

```
def update_shop
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  @user.update_attributes(shop_id: @shop.id)
  flash[:success] = "Added Shop!"
  redirect_to @shop
end
```

Here is the query in ShopsController#Customers

```
def customers
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
  @customers = Shop.users
end
```

This query gives me the error `undefined method 'users' for nil:NilClass`so users aren't being found with Shops.

How do I create the correct association when a user picks a shop rather than just updating the shop_id param?

Comment: What you ask is not really clear. Can you tell us what's wrong with the current approach, what doesn't work, what you want to do exactly... Are you facing any error ?

Comment: Edited to include the error

Comment: Well, the error is pretty explicit... Are you sure the `params[:id]` is assigned and match an existing shop... ?

Comment: in the customers action: `@customers = @shop.users`

Comment: Haha @TheCha͢mp ... How come I've missed that >.< But still, the error should be `undefined method users for Shop class`, right ?

Comment: ;) sometimes it needs a fresh pair of eyes - and yes, the error is wierd...

Comment: Yeah that error is from the @shop = Shop.find... line because the id being passed is nil. But in #show it works fine. Not sure how to get the id to pass?

Comment: If you don't want the error then use `find_by_id`, which will returns `nil` instead of raising an error

Comment: or `find_by(id: ...)` since you're using rails 4

Comment: I edited the error above, the real issue the question was getting at is `undefined method `users' for nil:NilClass` on @shop.users.  So how do I query all the users belonging to a shop?

Comment: try not to edit the question too much, or at least leave an history. For those who try to solve your problem, context is often needed

Comment: I commented when I added the error and edited it, sorry if it's confusing.  The question isn't coming across right though.  I need to get the association to work so I can pull all the users of a shop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88379/discussion-between-thomas-haratyk-and-virge-assault).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to have the users of a specific shop, not the relation of the ("abstract") `Shop` model. Thus you have to call `.users` on a shop **instance**, in your example `@shop` .

```
def customers
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    @customers = @shop.users
end
```

You question is not fully clear, but I hope this helps. Also note, that in your question text you actually ask about `@shop.users`, but your code example reads `Shop.users` :) . I think you have two questions actually: How to access all users of a shop ("How to access associated instances?") and "How to assign an object to a belongs_to relation"?

Note that your `customers` method asserts that a shop with that id can be found (otherwise an error will be thrown).

To set the shop, you can use ActiveRecord like that:

```
@shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
@user.shop = @shop
```